# How to restrict dynamic input to one digit only and locked for key press except spin buttons using pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have created a dynamic input and its should accept numbers between 0 to 5 only using spinner (arrow buttons) and should restrict manual input from key board. I have tried `[this][1]` but its not working in my code. I have two java script files data.js contains object to be read and other file contains a function which read objects and display them dynamically  Please help me knowing where I am doing mistake? Thank you

```js
//data.js
var catalogArray = [
    {
      code: 100,
      name: "T Shirt c100",
      desc: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known as",
      price: 150,
      image: "./images/img100.jpg"
    },
    {
      code:101 ,
      name: "T Shirt c101",
       desc: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known as",
      price: 250,
      image: "./images/img101.jpg"
    }
    ];


//function.js
function chargerArticles() {
 var articles = document.getElementById("content");
 var catalog=catalogArray;
 for (var i =0; i < catalog.length; i++) {


  //Command Input Area
  var zoneCmd=document.createElement("div");
  zoneCmd.setAttribute("class", "border");
  
  var inputCmd=document.createElement("Input");
  inputCmd.setAttribute("class", "qty");

  
  //inputcmd all properties
  inputCmd.type="number";
  // inputcmd.maxLenght="1";
  // inputcmd.onKeydown=false;
  inputCmd.value=0;
  inputCmd.min=0;
  inputCmd.max=5;
  zoneCmd.appendChild(inputCmd); //child 1


  //zoneCmd child of article element
  article.appendChild(zoneCmd);


  //finally article as a child of articles 
  articles.appendChild(article);

 }
 
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <script src="js/data.js"></script>
    <script src="js/codeboutique.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="chargerArticles()">



<!--  <div class="border"><input class="qty" id="0-qte" type="number" min="0" max="5"
"><button class="cartBtn hvr-underline-btn" id="0-cmd" 
"> ADD TO CART</button></div> -->

 <div class="mainDivClass">


    <section id="content">
    </section>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code snippet has fatal errors. Missing .js files, can't find variable: 'article'. Can you update your snippet to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what type of thing a "*spin button*" is, so I can't address that part of your question.

But another of your requirements is an input that does not respond to the keyboard.

This can be accomplished easily.

In order to prevent keyboard events from affecting an input, simply write a listener function that responds to 'keydown' events.

```js
let input = document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(input);
input.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  // console.log('keydown e.key:', e.key);

  // prevent default input response
  e.preventDefault();

  // take action on up or down arrow key
  if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    input.value = 'Up Arrow';
  } else if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
    input.value = 'Down Arrow';
  } else {
    console.log('key blocked: ', e.key);
  }

});
```

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts for providing this useful information. In first part of question I want to prevent all keys except key-up and key-down. key up and down should work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Ayes Just check for 'ArrowUp' or 'ArrowDown' and take appropriate action. See my updated answer.